# what's the best way to alts!! on a vector of channel multiple times?

Tags: clojure, core.async

I'm using core.async to do something in parallel, and then using `alts!!` wait on certain amount of result with timeout.

```
(ns c
  (:require [clojure.core.async :as a]))

(defn async-call-on-vector [v]
  (mapv (fn [n]
          (a/go (a/<! (a/timeout n)) ; simulate long time work
                n))
        v))

(defn wait-result-with-timeout [chans num-to-get timeout]
  (let [chans-count (count chans)
        num-to-get (min num-to-get
                        chans-count)]
    (if (empty? chans)
      []
      (let [timeout (a/timeout timeout)]
        (loop [result []
               met 0]
          (if (or (= (count result) num-to-get)
                  (= met chans-count)) ; all chan has been consumed
            result
            (let [[v c] (a/alts!! (conj chans timeout))]
              (if (= c timeout)
                result
                (case v
                  nil (do (println "got nil") (recur result met)) ; close! on that channel
                  (recur (conj result v) (inc met)))))))))))
```

and then invoke like:

```
user=> (-> [1 200 300 400 500] c/async-call-on-vector (c/wait-result-with-timeout 2 30))
```

this expression will prints out a lot of `got nil`. It seems channel returned by go block will close that channel after result has been returned. And this will causes `alts!!` return nil on this case. but this is very CPU unfriendly, it just like busy waiting. Is there a way to avoid this?

I solved this by define a macro like go, but return a channel that will not closed on result returned. Is this a right way to solve it?

Comment: Did you look at async pipeline function? Looks very similar - https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async.clj#L470

Comment: @edbond well, the use case is different, but after I read library, I think `merge` is appropriate for my need, except I have to wrap it with timeout. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using core.async to do something in parallel, and then using alts!! wait on certain amount of result with timeout.

It looks like you want to collect all of the values that will be delivered by some channels, until all of those channels are closed, or until a timeout occurs. One way to do that is to `merge` those channels onto a single channel, and then use `alts!` within a `go-loop` to collect the values into a vector:

```
(defn wait-result-with-timeout [chans timeout]
  (let [all-chans (a/merge chans)
        t-out (a/timeout timeout)]
    (a/go-loop [vs []]
      (let [[v _] (a/alts! [all-chans t-out])]
        ;; v will be nil if either every channel in
        ;; `chans` is closed, or if `t-out` fires.
        (if (nil? v)
          vs
          (recur (conj vs v)))))))
```

> It seems channel returned by go block will close that channel after result has been returned.

You are correct, that is the documented behavior of a go block.

> I solved this by define a macro like go, but return a channel that will not closed on result returned. Is this a right way to solve it?

Probably not, although it's not for me to say whether it's right or wrong for your particular use case. Generally speaking, channels should close if they are done delivering values, to indicate the semantics of being done delivering values. For example, the above code uses the closing of `all-chans` to indicate that there is no more work to wait on.